# Action bar not hidding in a processing application generated on a smartphone

Tags: xml, processing, config

I code in a smartphone with Processing.
But the apk generated show the actionbar at the bottom.

I want to hide that, but it is impossible, there is just very limited options.

I have try to decompile with apktool for android the manifest xml but the problem remain the same.

I have done all internet search but all the solutions fails.

The Actionbar is always on bottom of the application, not a true fullscreen mode.

Hide the action bar, hide everythink around the processing application.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is no action bar with the following code in the Processing IDE.  The theme in the manifest is set to prevent it:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
```

```
void setup() {
  fullScreen();
  background(109);
}

void draw() {  
}
```